# como guardar el id de un select from de mi tabla usuarios y luego insertar en un insert php en mi tabla asistencia y mysql

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, mysqli, php7

por favor me podrian ayudar en este tipo de error como puedo traer un id de mi select from y insertarle en mi consulta de insert...¡¡¡

```
<?php
include("conexion.php");

    $fecha=date('Y-m-d'); 
    $status= $_POST['status'];

    $dni=$_POST['dni'];

    $passadmin=$_POST['passadmin'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE dni = '$dni' AND passadmin ='$passadmin' and rol='2'";
    //$query = $conexion->query($sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);

    extract($row);    

    $id = $row['id'];

    $query="INSERT INTO entrada (id,fecha,hora,status) VALUES ('$id','$fecha',NOW(),'$status')";
```

Comment: Con la función `extract` ya estás obteniendo los valores del array asociativo por lo que no es necesario que guardes el valor de `$id`, ya que esa variable con su valor se crea automáticamente al usar `extract` por lo que lo podrías usar en tu sentencia insert directamente. Por otro lado, si el `$id` es numérico no le pongas las comillas simples al insertarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener los datos debes mandar a ejecutar la consulta primero, mediante el método `query` en este caso. Eso no lo estás haciendo.

Tampoco necesitas `extract` para sacar los datos, puedes hacerlo simplemente como `$row["id"]`, una vez hayas hecho el fetch.

Luego, hay varios vacíos en tu código, muchas cosas se dan por supuestas. Hay que prever cualquier eventualidad y establecer controles en cada caso.

Otra cosa es que no declares variables ni incluyas archivos hasta no estar seguro de que los vas a usar.

Aplicamos todo lo dicho y otras cosas aquí, he puesto varios comentarios para ayudar a entender lo que se ha ido haciendo.

```
#Variable de información
$msg="";
#Verificar datos posteados
$dni=!empty($_POST['dni']) ? $_POST['dni'] : NULL;
$passadmin=!empty($_POST['passadmin']) ? $_POST['passadmin'] : NULL;

if ( $dni && $passadmin )
{
    #Incluir los archivos cuando se esté seguro de que se van a usar
    include("conexion.php");
    #Traer sólo el dato que se requiere, el id y limitar a una fila
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM login WHERE dni = '$dni' AND passadmin ='$passadmin' and rol='2' LIMIT 1";
    #Verificar si no hay error de consulta
    if ( $query = $conexion->query($sql) ) 
    {
        #Verificar si no hay una consulta vacía
        if ( $query->num_rows > 0 ) 
        {
            $row = $query->fetch_assoc();
            #No hay necesidad de usar extract para esto
            $id=$row["id"];
            $fecha=date('Y-m-d'); 
            $status= $_POST['status'];
            $sql="INSERT INTO entrada (id,fecha,hora,status) VALUES ($id,'$fecha',NOW(),'$status')";
            if ( $query = $conexion->query($sql) ) 
            {
                $msg.="Filas insertadas: ".$query->affected_rows;
            } else {
                $msg.="Error: {$conexion->error}";
            }
        } else {
            $msg.="No se encontraron filas en el SELECT";               
        }

    } else {
        $msg.="Error: {$conexion->error}";
    }
} else {
    $msg.="Faltan datos en el POST";            
}
echo $msg;
```

Espero te sirva. Cualquier error o duda, puedes comentar.